# Правописание числительных

Tags: орфография, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Трое подростков попали в больницу или три подростка попали в больницу - как правильно?

Comment: @Харлампий Опуич, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта действительно возможны, но разный оттенок смысла всё-таки есть.

Лучше сказать - трое подростков, выразив значение собирательности, тогда будет понятно, что они имеют отношение к одному происшествию (не к трем разным случаям).

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту!

Answer (score 2):

С лицами мужского пола возможно оба варианта.

Comment: Слово подросток в одинаковой мере относится и к мужскому и к женскому полу! Точно так же звучит и - трое человек и- три человека! Как же правильно?

Comment: Слово подросток хотя и относится к обеим полам, но грамматически оно муж.рода.Собирательные числительные могут также употребляться с существительными так называемого общего рода: трое друзей, четверо сирот.  Что касается "трое человек" , то здесь правильно только: три человека. НИКАКИХ ТРОЕ ЧЕЛОВЕК. Со словом "люди",здесь справочники теоретически допускают сочетаемость с собирательными числительными. Но в качестве примере приводят такое предложение: трое молодых людей.

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Можно только ОБЪЯСНИТЬ запрет на "трое человек". Человек - это сущ. ед. числа. Мы можем сказать два/три/четыре человека, так как эти количественные обороты как раз и требуют Форму ед. числа. Но почему мы говорим "пять человек"? Дело в том, что форма ед.числа "человек" просто СОВПАДАЕТ с формой "человек" мн.числа Р.п.  и поэтому разрешена для применения. Но вот в праве выражать значение собирательности форме "человек" категорически отказано.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, София и Серж, за быстрые, доходчивые и понятные объяснения!

Comment: Рады помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный вариант - три подростка. Словосочетание выступает в роли подлежащего, соответственно только именительный падеж.